# Setting user defined signal actions and defaults (macOS and Linux)

Tags: c, sigaction

I need a function that allows to either specify a user defined signal action, to reset it to default, or to ignore the signal. The code so far is

```
int setsig(int signum,  void (*action)(int, siginfo_t *, void *)) {
  struct sigaction sig;

  sigemptyset (&sig.sa_mask);
  sig.sa_sigaction = action;
  sig.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER|SA_SIGINFO;

  return sigaction (code, &sig, NULL); 
}
```

This shall later be used in a code like

```
static void my_action (int, siginfo_t *, void *);

void (*mysignal)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);

if (some_condition) {
    mysignal = my_action;
} else if (some_other_contion) {
    mysignal = SIG_IGN;
} else {
    mysignal = SIG_DFL;
}
[…]

setsig(signum, mysignal);
```

However, this wrongly treats `SIG_IGN` and `SIG_DFL` as sigactions and not as sighandlers.
Are there (portable) equivalents as actions? Or is there another way to have them handled in a similar way?

Comment: So; I need to handle my own action and `SIG_IGN` resp. `SIG_DFN` in a similar way. And since I need the additional info in `siginfo_t`, I can't use `signal()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Aconcagua's answer is more flexible (since it allows additional handlers of type `void (*)(int)` to be used), but if the only values of type `void (*)(int)` you need to handle are the special values `SIG_IGN` and `SIG_DFL` you could use a type-cast operator to convert them and add code to `setsig()` to check for these special values:

```
#define SET_SIG_IGN ((void (*)(int, siginfo_t *, void *))SIG_IGN)
#define SET_SIG_DFL ((void (*)(int, siginfo_t *, void *))SIG_DFL)
```

```
int setsig(int signum,  void (*action)(int, siginfo_t *, void *)) {
  struct sigaction sig;

  sigemptyset (&sig.sa_mask);
  if (action == SET_SIG_IGN || action == SET_SIG_DFL) {
    sig.sa_handler = (void (*)(int))action;
    sig.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
  } else {
    sig.sa_sigaction = action;
    sig.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER|SA_SIGINFO;
  }

  return sigaction (signum, &sig, NULL); 
}
```

```
static void my_action (int, siginfo_t *, void *);

[…]
    void (*mysignal)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    […]
    if (some_condition) {
        mysignal = my_action;
    } else if (some_other_contion) {
        mysignal = SET_SIG_IGN;
    } else {
        mysignal = SET_SIG_DFL;
    }
    […]
    setsig(signum, mysignal);
```

This assumes that the values `SIG_IGN` and `SIG_DFL` of type `void (*)(int)` can be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again and compare equal to the original value in the same way that pointers to actual functions do (ref: C17 6.3.2.3 paragraph 8).

Comment: Thank you; this is IMO the best compromise between complexity and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could use C's overload mechanism:

```
void set_signal_action(int signal, void(*)(int))
{
    // install signal action
}
void set_signal_handler(int signal, void(*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*))
{
    // install signal handler
}

#define setSignalHandler(signal, X) _Generic                \
    (                                                       \
        (X),                                                \
        void(*)(int):                    set_signal_action, \
        void(*)(int, siginfo_t*, void*): set_signal_handler \
    )(signal, X)
```

This way you could use the same handler for any of the two types, though you would have to install it *immediately*:

```
if (some_condition)
{
    setSignalHandler(s, my_action);
}
else if(some_other_condition)
{
    setSignalHandler(s, SIG_IGN);
}
else
{
    setSignalHandler(s, SIG_DFL);
}
```

To actually install the signal handler at a later point of time you might modify the setter functions above to accept instead of the signal (`int`) a `struct sigaction*` parameter such that the appropriate member is set and the flags are adjusted accordingly without already installing the handler (leaving this to you...).